# Approximately putting integers into buckets such that the sum of bucket differences is minimized

Tags: java, combinatorics

I have the need for load balancing in my MSD-radix sort routine and doing it optimally is not an option. So I tried to play with two simple routines for putting integers into a prespecified amount of buckets such that the sums of buckets are "close" to each other.

My main question is: Can you suggest more optimal, polynomial-time algorithm for doing this. (I think my needs can tolerate at most \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$.)

Java implementation follows:

**LoadBalancer.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.alg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class defines two simple routines for putting integers into specified
 * amount of buckets such that the sums of buckets are close to each other.
 * However, these are approximations, but run in linearithmic 
 * (<tt>O(n log n)</tt>)time each.
 */
public class LoadBalancer {

    private static final int MAXIMUM_PRINT_ARRAY_LENGTH = 50;
    private static final int BAR_LENGTH = 80;

    /**
     * This is a basic approximation routine for distributing integers in
     * <code>array</code>  into <code>buckets</code> buckets. It works by 
     * sorting the clone array into ascending order and loading from left to
     * right into each bucket until each bucket becomes "full".
     * 
     * @param  input   the array of input integers. Is not modified.
     * @param  buckets the amount of buckets.
     * 
     * @return         a partition, which is a list of lists, each representing
     *                 a bucket.
     */
    public static List<List<Integer>> partition1(final int[] input,
                                                 final int buckets) {
        checkIntArray(input);
        checkBucketAmount(buckets);

        final int[] array = input.clone();
        final List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<>(buckets);

        for (int i = 0; i < buckets; ++i) {
            ret.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        Arrays.sort(array);

        int totalArraySum = 0;

        for (final int integer : array) {
            totalArraySum += integer;
        }

        final int MINIMUM_BUCKET_LOAD = totalArraySum / buckets;

        int integerIndex = 0;
        int bucketIndex = 0;
        int loaded = 0;

        // Load the buckets.
        while (integerIndex < array.length) {
            while (integerIndex < array.length && loaded < MINIMUM_BUCKET_LOAD) {
                final int currentInteger = array[integerIndex++];
                ret.get(bucketIndex).add(currentInteger);
                loaded += currentInteger;
            }

            // Proceed to the next bucket.
            ++bucketIndex;
            loaded = 0;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * This is a basic approximation routine for distributing integers in
     * <code>array</code>  into <code>buckets</code> buckets. It works by 
     * sorting the clone array into ascending order and then loads to the first
     * bucket the smallest integer, the largest integer, the second smallest
     * integer, the second largest integers, and so on until each bucket becomes
     * "full".
     * 
     * @param  input   the array of input integers. Is not modified.
     * @param  buckets the amount of buckets.
     * 
     * @return         a partition, which is a list of lists, each representing
     *                 a bucket.
     */
    public static List<List<Integer>> partition2(final int[] input,
                                                 final int buckets) {
        checkIntArray(input);
        checkBucketAmount(buckets);

        int[] array = input.clone();
        final List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<>(buckets);

        for (int i = 0; i < buckets; ++i) {
            ret.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        Arrays.sort(array);

        int totalArraySum = 0;

        for (final int integer : array) {
            totalArraySum += integer;
        }

        final int MINIMUM_BUCKET_LOAD = totalArraySum / buckets;
        final int[] work = new int[array.length];

        int workIndex = 0;
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = array.length - 1;

        // Put to work smallest integer, then the largest integer,
        // then the second smallest integer, then second largest integer, and
        // so on.
        while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
            work[workIndex++] = array[leftIndex++];
            work[workIndex++] = array[rightIndex--];
        }

        // If the array has odd length, we need to copy to work the middle 
        // element.
        if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
            work[workIndex] = array[leftIndex];
        }

        array = work;

        int integerIndex = 0;
        int bucketIndex = 0;
        int loaded = 0;

        // Load the buckets.
        while (integerIndex < array.length) {
            while (integerIndex < array.length && loaded < MINIMUM_BUCKET_LOAD) {
                final int currentInteger = array[integerIndex++];
                ret.get(bucketIndex).add(currentInteger);
                loaded += currentInteger;
            }

            // Proceed to the next bucket.
            ++bucketIndex;
            loaded = 0;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final int SIZE = 30;
        final int MAX = 100;
        final long SEED = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int BUCKET_AMOUNT = 5;
        final Random rnd = new Random(SEED);
        System.out.println("Seed: " + SEED);

        final int[] array = getRandomIntegerArray(SIZE, MAX, rnd);

        List<List<Integer>> partition = partition1(array, BUCKET_AMOUNT);

        println(array);
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum(array));
        printBar();
        printPartition(partition);
        System.out.println("Sum of pairwise differences: " +
                countPairwiseDifferenceSums(partition));
        printBar();
        partition = partition2(array, BUCKET_AMOUNT);
        printPartition(partition);
        System.out.println("Sum of pairwise differences: " +
                countPairwiseDifferenceSums(partition));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random array of nonnegative integers.
     * 
     * @param size the length of the array.
     * @param max  the maximum value of a array component.
     * @param rnd  the random number generator.
     * 
     * @return a random array of integers.
     */
    private static int[] getRandomIntegerArray(final int size,
                                               final int max,
                                               final Random rnd) {
        final int[] array = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            array[i] = rnd.nextInt(max + 1);
        }

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Counts the sum of absolute differences between all the integer buckets.
     * 
     * @param buckets the list of buckets, where each bucket is represented by
     *                a list of integers.
     * @return        the sum of bucket differences.
     */
    private static int countPairwiseDifferenceSums(
            final List<List<Integer>> buckets) {
        final int[] bucketSumArray = new int[buckets.size()];

        for (int index = 0; index < bucketSumArray.length; ++index) {
            for (final Integer i : buckets.get(index)) {
                bucketSumArray[index] += i;
            }
        }

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bucketSumArray.length - 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < bucketSumArray.length; ++j) {
                sum += Math.abs(bucketSumArray[i] - bucketSumArray[j]);
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Prints a funky separation bar.
     */
    private static void printBar() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < BAR_LENGTH; ++i) {
            sb.append('-');
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Prints information about the input partition.
     * 
     * @param partition the partition to print.
     */
    private static void printPartition(final List<List<Integer>> partition) {
        int totalSum = 0;

        for (final List<Integer> bucket : partition) {
            System.out.print("[");

            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < bucket.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.print(bucket.get(i));

                if (i < bucket.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }

                sum += bucket.get(i);
            }

            System.out.println("] Sum: " + sum);
            totalSum += sum;
        }

        System.out.println("Total element sum: " + totalSum);
    }


    /**
     * Prints the entire integer array on a single line.
     * 
     * @param array the array to print.
     */
    private static void println(final int[] array) {
        if (array.length > MAXIMUM_PRINT_ARRAY_LENGTH) {
            System.out.println("(The array is too large to print!)");
            return;
        }

        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);

            if (i < array.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("]");
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sum of integers within the input array.
     * 
     * @param  array the array to sum.
     * 
     * @return the sum of integers.
     */
    private static int sum(final int[] array) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (final int i : array) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private static void checkIntArray(final int[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The integer array reference is null.");
        }
    }

    private static void checkBucketAmount(final int buckets) {
        if (buckets < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "At least one bucket is required. Received " + buckets);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://www.mysmu.edu/faculty/kyriakos/IJCAI11.pdf. Looks tough but promising.

Answer (score 3):

## Partition using a heap

Here is a method that should give a more even partitioning while still using linearithmic time:

1. Sort the array of numbers in *descending* order.
2. Add all the buckets to a min-heap, sorted by their current weight.  They all start empty with weight 0.
3. For each number in the sorted array, place the number in the bucket at the top of the heap.  (This will place the largest remaining number in the bucket with the least weight.)  Increase the weight of the bucket by the amount just added, and fix up the heap by using a sift down operation.

The bucket placement in step 3 should take \$O(n\log n)\$ time.  The partitioning should be more even than the two ways that you have attempted, because it uses the smaller elements to "fill in the gaps" at the end.

Note: This answer is 8 months late but I was just looking for an interesting unanswered question to answer.